# UWP MapControl: How to prevent zoom on MapDoubleTapped?

Tags: uwp, .net-core, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I need to catch a double click/tap event on a map polygon in order to show an "edit properties" dialog. How can I prevent the map zoom on double tap (on a polygon)? There is no e.Handled property available. The map must still be zoomable by double tapping on free space (no polygon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can disable the zooming when double clicking:

```
MyMapControl.MapDoubleTapped += MyMapControl_MapDoubleTapped;

private void MyMapControl_MapDoubleTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
{
    var currentCamera = sender.ActualCamera;
    sender.TrySetSceneAsync(MapScene.CreateFromCamera(currentCamera));
}
```

If you only want to disable this when a polygon is double tapped. Try using setting the scene in your polygon double tap event handler.

Comment: It works for zoom levels < ~10.6, with higher zoom levels it zooms on double tap again!

Answer (score 0):

this should work in all zoom levels

```
    private async void OnMapDoubleTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
    {
        double zoom = sender.ZoomLevel;
        var camera= sender.ActualCamera;
        await sender.TrySetViewAsync(camera.Location, zoom);
    }
```